# What did this do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, terminal-server

I found this line

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

as the first command used by root on my server. I think it looks like someone wanted to disable the user accounts somehow, but I'm having trouble making everything else work now. Does anyone know what it does?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because man pages are on your system for a reason. Use them before asking for help here, please.

Answer (score 5):

That command outputs a list of usernames on the system.

`cut` is a command used to process text according to columns.
`-d:` tells the command that columns are delimited by the `:` character.
`-f1` tells the command to display only the first field. `/etc/passwd` is the file it is to read data from.

The `/etc/passwd` file contains a line for each user. Each line has columns separated by `:` the first of which is the username.

It will only display accounts defined locally on the machine. If the machine is configured to retrieve account information from a network service, there may be more accounts than those you can find in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 2):

[man cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)

`-d:` set <kbd>:</kbd> as the field delimiter
`-f1` select field number <kbd>1</kbd>

Selects the first field of `/etc/passwd` in other words print a list with user names...

Comment: There you go RMAAS